# Syntax error or access violation: 1064 | Sending array using Doctrine (QueryBuilder)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I'm coming to you because I'm having trouble sending array in POST request. I've created a RESTAPI in Symfony 4.3.11.

This code is working if I'm sending only 1 string in each array :

```php
            $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Application::class);

            $query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('request');
            $query
                ->andWhere($query->expr()->Andx(
                    $query->expr()->eq('request.curr', ':curr'),
                    $query->expr()->eq('request.country', ':JSONcountry'),
                    $query->expr()->eq('request.type', ':JSONtype'),
                    $query->expr()->eq('request.job', ':JSONjob'),
                ))
                ->setParameter('curr', true)
                ->setParameter('JSONcountry', $app->getCountry())
                ->setParameter('JSONtype', $app->getType())
                ->setParameter('JSONjob', $app->getJob());

            echo $query;
            $query = $query->getQuery();
            $applications = $query->getResult();

            return $applications;
```

But when I try to send this type of JSON :

```json
{
    "caisse":["FRANCE", "ESPAGNE"],
    "type":["FR", "ES"],
    "job":["CHIEF", "TEST"]
}
```

It's returning this error :

```json
    "code": 500,
    "message": "An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT ...' with params [1, \"FRANCE\", \"ESPAGNE\", \"FR\", \"ES\", \"CHEF\", \"TEST\"]:\n\nSQLSTATE[42000]: 
    Syntax error or access violation: 1064"

}
```

I've searched the error on the Web, and find that this error is showing often when a syntax is wrong or when something is missing, but in my case, the code is working.

I also have a second question : In my case, how to do the "LIKE" operator for each string in array ?
I have saw a way to do it but for string only : `->setParameter('JSONcountry', '%' . $app->getCountry() . '%')`

If you have any questions or suggestions about my code, feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parameter is an array, you should use $query->expr()->in(...) function instead of equal. I am assuming you are looking for objects that match any of the elements in the array.

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Application::class);

$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('request');
$query
    ->andWhere($query->expr()->Andx(
        $query->expr()->eq('request.curr', ':curr'),
        $query->expr()->in('request.country', ':JSONcountry'),
        $query->expr()->in('request.type', ':JSONtype'),
        $query->expr()->in('request.job', ':JSONjob'),
   ))
   ->setParameter('curr', true)
   ->setParameter('JSONcountry', $app->getCountry())
   ->setParameter('JSONtype', $app->getType())
   ->setParameter('JSONjob', $app->getJob());

echo $query;
$query = $query->getQuery();
$applications = $query->getResult();

return $applications;
```

Comment: It's working like I wanted to with this @diegowc. Do you know how can I add my LIKE operator for each string in my array ?
For example, I have a "type" in my database which is "FR, fra", and currently it didn't return it.

Comment: You can do $query->andWhere('request.x LIKE :x')->setParameter('x', '%' . $x . '%') but that won't work if $x is an array. In your case you would need to do a for loop for that array, and on each iteration add the LIKE comparison $query->andWhere('request.x LIKE :x' . $index)->setParameter('x' . $index, '%' . $x[$index] . '%')